# AngularJS directive getting called before Jquery AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax

I am getting some data via a jquery ajax call and trying to load it into an angularjs chart (specifically using NVD3.org). However the chart is loading before the ajax calls finishes and data is retrieved, how do I make the chart wait for the ajax call to finish?

```
<script>
    var dataxx= [{"x": 0, "y": 0},{"x": 4, "y": 5}];
    dataxx.push({"x":9,"y":11});
    $( document).ready(function (){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET", 
            url: "https://demo8162910.mockable.io/json",
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonp: true,
            jsonpCallback: "myJsonMethod",
            error: function(){
                alert( 'Unable to load feed, Incorrect path or invalid feed' );
            },
            success: function(data){
                dataxx.push({"x":9,"y":11,"$$hashKey":"object:13","series":0});
                for (i in data)
                {
                    //dataxx.push({x: 4, y: 5});
                    //$( "#postlist" ).append(data[i].id);
                }   

                //alert(dataxx);
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(dataxx));

            }});
    });
</script>


<script>


 angular.module('app',  ['onsen'])

    .controller('ChartController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      this.data = [{
        key: 'Data',
        values: dataxx
      }];
    }])

    .factory('d3', [function() {
      return d3;
    }])

    .factory('nv', [function() {
      return nv;
    }])

    .directive('lineChart', ['d3', 'nv', function(d3, nv) {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
          data: '=',
          height: '@',
          width: '@'
        },
        template: '<svg ng-attr-height="{{ height }}" ng-attr-width="{{ width }}"></svg>',
        link: function(scope, element) {
          var svg = element.find('svg'),
            chart;

          var update = function() {
            d3.select(svg[0])
              .datum(scope.data)
              .call(chart);
          };

          scope.$watch(function() { return angular.toJson(scope.data); }, function() {
            if (chart) {
              update();
            }
          });

          scope.$on('chartloaded', update);

          nv.addGraph(function() {
            chart = nv.models.lineChart()
              .showLegend(false)
              .showYAxis(true)
              .showXAxis(true);

            chart.xAxis
              .axisLabel('x')
              .tickFormat(d3.format('.2f'));

            chart.yAxis
              .axisLabel('y')
              .tickFormat(d3.format('.2f'));

            nv.utils.windowResize(function() {
              chart.update()
            });

            scope.$emit('chartloaded');

            return chart;
          });
        }
      }
    }]);        




</script>



<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ChartController as main">
                              <line-chart height="250px" data="main.data"></line-chart>

                            </div>
```

Comment: so, not use jQuery separated, use request in angular

Comment: You can use `$http` service, instead of JQuery Ajax function,
`$http.jsonp('https://demo8162910.mockable.io/json?callback=myJsonMethod').then(function(response){
console.log(response);});`

Comment: Tried this but get error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { for line with the $http.json call and also error : Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to: Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'app' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the de...<omitted>...2)

Comment: Where would I place the $http.jsonp('https://demo8162910.mockable.io/json?callback=myJsonMethod').then(‌​function(response){ console.log(response);});

Comment: I need to loop through the response before passing it into the values array for the chart... I think Jquery might work better for this...

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
 angular.module('app',  ['onsen'])
    .controller('ChartController', ['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http) {
      $scope.data = [{
        key: 'Data',
        values: []
      }];
      $http.jsonp('https://demo8162910.mockable.io/json?callback=myJsonMethod').then(‌​function(response){ 
         console.log(response);
      //format response
      $scope.data = [{
        key: 'Data',
        values: response
      }];
     });
    }])

    .factory('d3', [function() {
      return d3;
    }])

    .factory('nv', [function() {
      return nv;
    }])

    .directive('lineChart', ['d3', 'nv', function(d3, nv) {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
          data: '=',
          height: '@',
          width: '@'
        },
        template: '<svg ng-attr-height="{{ height }}" ng-attr-width="{{ width }}"></svg>',
        link: function(scope, element) {
          var svg = element.find('svg'),
            chart;

          var update = function() {
            d3.select(svg[0])
              .datum(scope.data)
              .call(chart);
          };

          scope.$watch(function() { return angular.toJson(scope.data); }, function() {
            if (chart) {
              update();
            }
          });

          scope.$on('chartloaded', update);

          nv.addGraph(function() {
            chart = nv.models.lineChart()
              .showLegend(false)
              .showYAxis(true)
              .showXAxis(true);

            chart.xAxis
              .axisLabel('x')
              .tickFormat(d3.format('.2f'));

            chart.yAxis
              .axisLabel('y')
              .tickFormat(d3.format('.2f'));

            nv.utils.windowResize(function() {
              chart.update()
            });

            scope.$emit('chartloaded');

            return chart;
          });
        }
      }
    }]);        
</script>


 <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ChartController as main">
      <line-chart height="250px" data="main.data"></line-chart>
    </div>
```

Comment: Tried this but get error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { for line with the $http.json call and also error : Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'app' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the de...<omitted>...2)

Comment: add $http service to controller and try